# clear screen using exec() in linux

Tags: c, linux, exec, fork

I am trying to write a code that will clear the screen by using fork() through exec. But by referring http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html manual i am confuse why this is not placing new image at the screen( i mean clearing the screen).

here is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
# include <curses.h>
#define NUMARGS 2



void main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    char * child_args[NUMARGS] = {0,0};


    if((pid=fork())==0){

        exec();// clear the screen

    }
    else{

        wait();



    }


}
```

Kindly correct me if its wrong so that i can solve this problem.

Comment: Both your question and your program make no sense.

Comment: is it possible to use exec to clear the screen bcz i am trying to clear the screen using child process

Comment: `exec()` is not listed on the page you linked

Comment: on Description:  "The 'exec()' family of functions replaces the current process image
       with a new process image.  The functions described in this manual
       page are front-ends for execve(2).  (See the manual page for
       execve(2) for further details about the replacement of the current
       process image.)"

Comment: I don't think you understand what the manual means by `image`

Comment: You can think of these images as instances of a program. It has nothing to do with output / graphical representation.

Comment: what i am trying is to clear the screen using exec( from any type of exec) is it possible?

Comment: It is definitely possible, but why do you want to do that ? It's completely overkill.

Comment: overkill mean? killing parent as well?

Comment: Actually i am doing semester project and my professor scolded me not to use shortcuts e.g system('clear'), printf("\033[2J"); he says this is asking the system to do so, your are not creating your ownshell. so i am trying to build such clear function that does when using child my all other processes are under child

Comment: Then your prof is an idiot. Something like `printf("\033[2J")`is the best you can do (on systems that support it). On windows you can use the console functions to write blanks to the buffer. Note that these solutions are not portable. For portability you would use something like curses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems to be confused about two different, unrelated things:

- `exec*()` and `fork()`
- Clearing the screen

`fork` create a new child process, duplicating the state of the current process at the same time.

`exec` is a family of related functions, whose job is to replace the current process by another.

On unix systems, clearing the screen is usually done via ANSI escape codes. Please do NOT print newlines in a loop instead, that's totally cheap. If you need portability between terminal emulators, you can use libraries to abstract this task, such as `termcaps` or `(n)curses`.

---

You mentioned using a child process to clear the screen, I suspect you're trying to create some kind of shell. Anyway, you can use `fork()` to create the child, `waitpid()` it in the parent function, and clear the screen from the child, either directly, for example with `fputs(stdout, "\033[2J")`, or by `exec*()` 'in another executable.

---

I really don't know why you don't just clear the screen from the parent, however.